# Angular7 httpclient get call unable to parse PDF as blob

Tags: get, httpclient, angular7

Angular7 Httpclient GET request not allowing to set {responsetype: 'application/pdf'} I tried combinations of blob,bytearray etc.
Its treating as JSON and failing on JSON.parse

I tried diff combinations as arraybuffer, blob

```
let requestOptions: Object = {
/* angualr 7 is not allowing this for some reason  */
responseType: 'application/pdf'
}
/* not working */
return this.http.get<any>(this.streamURL , requestOptions);
```

Please i need a way out to read the response as PDF instead as JSON.

Comment: same problem but for me it's json not pdf